# Distinct values 2d array

Tags: c#, .net

I have a 2D array as follows:

```
long[,] arr = new long[4, 4] {{ 5, 0, 0, 0 },
                              { 8, 1, 1, 1 },
                              { 0, 3, 0, 6 },
                              { 1, 1, 1, 1 }};
```

How I can display distinct values form this array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Distinct` method:

```
var uniqueValues = arr.Cast<long>().Distinct();
```